# Volley POST returns TimeoutError

Tags: android, http, timeout, android-volley

My question is regarding Google library Volley for android. I am doing HTTP post and getting TimeoutError. The same request made from curl returns fine. Here is url request (web site and passoword changed)

> curl -X POST --data
>   "debugger=curlsergiy&LoginID=myid&Operation=SimpleLogin&OutputJSON=2&Module=DataSource&Password=mypassword%21&"
>   https://mobile-demo.mycompany.com/csi-requesthandler/RequestHandler

Here is Volley based code

```
void makeTest() {
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://mobile-demo.mycompany.com/csi-requesthandler/RequestHandler",
                new Response.Listener<String> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response:" + response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Volley returned error:" + error);
                            Class klass = error.getClass();
                            if(klass == com.android.volley.AuthFailureError.class) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"AuthFailureError");
                            } else if(klass == com.android.volley.NetworkError.class) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"NetworkError");
                            } else if(klass == com.android.volley.NoConnectionError.class) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"NoConnectionError");
                            } else if(klass == com.android.volley.ServerError.class) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"ServerError");
                            } else if(klass == com.android.volley.TimeoutError.class) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"TimeoutError");
                            } else if(klass == com.android.volley.ParseError.class) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"ParseError");
                            } else if(klass == com.android.volley.VolleyError.class) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"General error");
                            }
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError{
                return "debugger=curlsergiy&LoginID=myid&Operation=SimpleLogin&OutputJSON=2&Module=DataSource&Password=mypassword%21&".getBytes();
            }
        };
        //set timeout and retry
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

And Volley output after 5 seconds
TimeoutError

Comment: OH GOD! Please format the code using Code tags. No one is going to be able to help you like this!

Comment: Problem solved. It was networking issue. Volley is great as promised. Again and again I can repeat - solve weird problems in the morning and go sleep at night LOL